# How to display radio Buttons one after the other in zend dojo form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo

I am working in zend framework application.
While coding a small screen I have been facing a problem as bellow.

The radio button is as bellow in zend dojo form:

```
$EmailRadio = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('EmailRadio')
       ->removeDecorator("DtDdWrapper")
       ->removeDecorator("Label")
       ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag')
       ->addMultiOptions(array('0' => 'Send Emails After Student Submit',
                               '1' => 'Send Emails After Chronepull'))
       ->setAttrib('dojoType',"dijit.form.RadioButton")
       ->setValue('0')  
       ->setSeparator('&nbsp');
```

But in my screen it is displaying as

[image]

**Output**: Required to display second radio button bellow the first radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
   ->setSeparator('&nbsp');
```

by

```
   ->setSeparator('<br>');
```

Comment: Thanks doydoy44...i got needfull.